# When to use Box<Vec<..>> or Vec<Box<..>>?

Tags: data-structures, rust

When would it make sense to design a data structure that is nesting a `Box` and a `Vec` (or vice versa)?

It seems like in most situations where you want to store multiple fixed-size things on the heap, the `Box` is redundant, since it's only (?) role is to heap-allocate a ~single value, and a normal `Vec` is already heap allocating its storage.

Context: I am still wrapping my head around the roles of the various Rust types for building up data structures.

Comment: The only use-case I can think of involve unsafe behavior, like wanting objects of the heap having a fixed pointer position even if the `Vec` reallocates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are really only a few times you need to use `Box`:

- Recursive data structures: not relevant for the outermost element, so no need for `Vec<Box<T>>`.
- Owned trait object, which must be `Box<Trait>` because the size of the object is dynamic;
- Things that are sensitive to particular memory addresses, in order that the contained object will keep the same memory location (practically never the case and definitely not the case in any stable public API; some of the handle stuff to do with `std::sync::mpsc::Select` is the only case that I am aware of; this unsafety and care required is a part of why [`select!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.select!.html) exists. This sort of a thing (`Handle.add`) is unsafe stuff.

If none of these situations apply, *you should not use `Box`*. And `Box<Vec<T>>` is one such case; the boxing is completely superfluous, adding an additional level of indirection to no benefit whatsoever.

So the simple version is:

- `Box<Vec<T>>`: never.
- `Vec<Box<T>>`: only if `T` is a trait, i.e. you’re working with trait objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Box<Vec<T>>` can be useful on rare occasions with `Option<Box<Vec<T>>>`, if you want to shrink the size of the struct (one word instead of three) and the vector is usually empty. [It was used in rustc for that, for example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/223d16ebbde1bd309c58e853b053e14318e56b0e/compiler/rustc_data_structures/src/thin_vec.rs). However, [lately it was replaced with the `thin-vec` crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100869), that does this better (still one word by storing the length and capacity inline, so does not require too allocations). If you don't want to introduce a dependency this can still be useful, though.