# Convert Vec<Box<Foo>> to &[&Foo] in Rust

Tags: reference, rust, type-conversion, slice

I am implementing a method on a struct which should return a `&[&Foo]` by borrowing a `Vec<Box<Foo>>` field. How would I implement this?

I have tried to do the conversion by mapping the `Vec<Box<Foo>>` into a `Vec<&Foo>`, however this is then allocated on the stack meaning a slice of it cannot be returned.

Here is an example of the problem:

```rust
struct Bar {
    baz: Vec<Box<Foo>>,
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn buzz(&self) -> &[&Foo] {
        // How do I implement this to return
        // the data that is in self.baz?
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Vec<Box<T>>` should only be used in very specific situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847928/when-to-use-boxvec-or-vecbox), such as when `T` is unsized. Otherwise, you may consider not using an extra layer of references. You may also consider not converting the boxes and simply returning `&[Box<Foo>]`, which is much easier to get in this situation.

Comment: You cannot do this without an allocation - you're either going to have to need an intermediate mapping step to turn `Box<Foo>` into `&Foo` (and even then this is risky, because you're implying Foo:Sized` by doing so in order to then have `Vec<&Foo>` and can call `as_slice()`, or you'll need to keep `&[Box<Foo>]` and allocate each element from there. What is your goal, though?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld In this case Foo is a trait object, meaning I have to wrap it in a box. I feel like using Vec<&Foo> for the return type would redundantly return an owned vector since it is conceptually just an immutable view of some existing data.

Comment: @SCappella Unfortunately Foo is indeed unsized, hence the box. Also I believe that returning &[Box<Foo>] implies ownership of each element which would not work.

Comment: @LLewVallis It's a *reference* to owned data. That doesn't imply ownership.

Comment: The `&` in `&[]` is indeed not there for esthetic reasons. It is not an owned structure.

Comment: Ok, I realized that a slice was not mutable as a collection (adding, removing, etc) but I didn't realize it implied that its elements were only accessible as references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with an `unsafe` coercion:

```
pub fn buzz(&self) -> &[&Foo] {
    unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.baz.as_ptr() as *const _, self.baz.len())
    }
}
```

This is sound because:

1. If `Foo` is dynamically sized, then `Box<Foo>` is a fat pointer. But then so is `&Foo`, so they always have the same layout.
2. The function signature enforces that the lifetime of the borrow cannot outlive the borrow of `&self`, so it is not possible for the boxes to be dropped while borrowed.

As others have hinted in comments, if you find yourself needing unsafe code for ostensibly simple cases, not catered for by `std`, then you may be working around a bad design decision in your own codebase. Avoid `unsafe` wherever possible and look critically at the entire design of your application before considering using it.

Comment: This works, but this doesn't really seem like a good idea. Conceptually I am just returning an immutable view over a collection of owned, unsized data. Is there something more idiomatic than returning a &[&Foo] that should be used? I feel like a Vec<&Foo> is a bit heavy since it would require shallow copying the vector for what is conceptually a borrow.

Comment: @Llew `&[Box<Foo>]` is just that: an immutable view over a collection of owned data. `&[&Foo]` would be a view over a collection of references to data, which you don't have. Since you don't have a `Vec<&Foo>`, you can't borrow a `&[&Foo]` without unsafe code (although as Peter points out, the use of `unsafe` here is sound).

Comment: @LlewVallis `&Foo` is a reference to a `Foo` anywhere on the stack or heap, it doesn't matter. `Box<Foo>` is specifically a reference to a `Foo` on the heap. So both `&[&Foo]` and `&[Box<Foo>]` are slices of pointers (fat pointers in this case).  So what is the advantage to the first form over the second?